# Loading Multiple Objects in A File

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am learning about objloader. May I know if there a way to allocate different objects in an obj file in THREE.JS so that I can manipulate each of them in different ways? For example I am loading an obj file, which contains two different objects, a box and a cylinder. Is there a way to put each of the objects in different meshes variable?

Comment: No, you need to save them in different files.

Comment: It seems the OBJLoader creates separate meshes if you youse the "o" command in obj file which starts a new object.